# Assigning constrained literal to a polymorphic variable

Tags: haskell, constraints

While learning haskell with [Haskell Programming from first principles](https://haskellbook.com/) found an exercise that puzzles me.

Here is the short version:

```
For the following definition:
   a) i :: Num a => a
      i = 1
   b) Try replacing the type signature with the following:
      i :: a
```

The replacement gives me an error:

```
error:
    • No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal ‘1’
      Possible fix:
        add (Num a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            i' :: forall a. a
    • In the expression: 1
      In an equation for ‘i'’: i' = 1
   |
38 | i' = 1
   |      ^
```

It is more or less clear for me how Num constraint arises.
What is not clear why assigning `1` to polymorphic variable `i'` gives the error.

Why this works:

```
id 1
```

while this one doesn't:

```
i' :: a
i' = 1
id i'
```

Should it be possible to assign a more specific value to a less specific and lose some type info if there are no issues?

Comment: `i' :: a` means that `i'` has a value that fits _any_ type, i.e. a value which is a function, as well as a list, as well as an integer, as well as a pair, etc. The definition `1` does not respect that. Indeed, nothing respects that type (except for infinite recursions like `i' = i'` which does not terminate).

Comment: If ```i'``` might have any value - why it cannot have ```Num``` constrained value?

Comment: @user1641854: That's the problem. `i'` can have any type - so what type should Haskell go for? Suppose I run a sandwich shop, which sells meat sandwiches, vegetarian sandwiches and vegan sandwiches - and you put in an order for 'sandwiches'. I can meet the order by supplying any kind of sandwiches - but am I free to do so, or in fact do I have a major problem?

Comment: Than why it is allowed to have ```id``` function that accepts any type and it's illegal to have unconstrained polymorphic variable?

Comment: Writing `i' :: a` allows the _user_ of `i'` to chose whatever type they want. It does not allow the _definition_ of `i'` to choose -- the definition must fit all the types that will be chosen, later on,  by the _user_. It is impossible to have a meaningful `i'`. Note that `id :: a->a` also allows the _user_ to choose whatever type `a` they want. However, the implementation `id x = x` indeed fits they type no matter what `a` will be chosen by the user. Here `a` is indeed unconstrained, since `id x = x` always works. By contrast, `id x = x+1` would fail to work when `x` is, e.g., a list.

Comment: I believe it is only possible to assign less specific (general) value to have more specific type. Not the other way around.

Comment: "If `i'` might have any value" -- to iron-man you, I'm going to change this quote to "If `i'` might have a value of any type". But that's not what the type signature `i' :: a` means; rather, it means that `i'` must have a value for *every* type. Some types are not `Num`-constrained, and `1` can't have a value for those types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding. You probably have something in mind like, in a class-OO language,

```cpp
class Object {};

class Num: Object { public: Num add(...){...} };

class Int: Num { int i; ... };
```

And then you would be able to use an `Int` value as the argument to a function that expects a `Num` argument, or a `Num` value as the argument to a function that expects an `Object`.

But that's not at all how Haskell's type classes work. `Num` is not a class of values (like, in the above example it would be the class of all values that belong to one of the subclasses). Instead, it's the class of all *types* that represent specific flavours of numbers.

How is that different? Well, a polymorphic literal like `1 :: Num a => a` does not generate a specific `Num` value that can then be upcasted to a more general class. Instead, it expects the caller to first pick a concrete type in which you want to render the number, then generates the number immediately in that type, and afterwards the type never changes.

In other words, a polymorphic value has an implicit type-level argument. Whoever wants to use `i` needs to do so in a context where both

1. It is unambiguous what type `a` should be used. (It doesn't necessarily need to be *fixed* right there: the caller could also itself be a polymorphic function.)
2. The compiler can prove that this type `a` has a `Num` instance.

In C++, the analogue of Haskell typeclasses / polymorphic literal is not [sub]classes and their objects, but instead *templates* that are constrained to a concept:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template<typename A>
concept Num = std::constructible_from<A, int>; // simplified

template<Num A>
A poly_1() {
  return 1;
}
```

Now, `poly_1` can be used in any setting that demands a type which fulfills the `Num` concept, i.e. in particular a type that is [`constructible_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/constructible_from) an `int`, but not in a context which requires some other type.

(In older C++ such a template would just be duck-typed, i.e. it's not explicit that it requires a `Num` setting but the compiler would just try to use it as such and then give a type error upon noticing that `1` can't be converted to the specified type.)

Comment: Another possible C++ translation: `i :: Num a => a; i = 1`, spelled out verbosely as `i :: forall (a :: Type). Num a => a; i = fromInteger @a 1`, is similar to `template<class A> A i(Num<A> const &num_a) { return num_a.from_integer(1); }`. When we omit the `Num` constraint in `i' :: a; i' = 1`, that corresponds to `template<class A> A i() { return …; }`, and we can’t call `.from_integer()` because we quite literally _don’t have an instance_ on which to call it.

Answer (score 3):

### tl;dr

A value `i'` declared as `i' :: a` must be usable¹ in place of any other value, with no exception. `1` is no such a value, as it can't be used, say, where a `String` is expected, just to make one example.

### Longer version

Let's start form a less uncontroversial scenario where you do need a type constraint:

```
plus :: a -> a -> a
plus x y = x + y
```

This does not compile, because the signature is equivalent to `plus :: forall a. a -> a -> a`, and it is plainly not true that the RHS, `x + y`, is meaningful for any common type `a` that `x` and `y` are inhabitants of. So you can fix the above by providing a constraint guaranteeing that `+` is possible between two `a`s, and you can do so by putting `Num a =>` right after `::` (or even by giving up on polymorphic types and just change `a` to `Int`).

But there are functions that don't require any constraints on their arguments. Here's three of them:

```hs
id :: a -> a
id x = x

const :: a -> b -> a
const x _ = x

Data.Tuple.swap :: (a, b) -> (b, a)
Data.Tuple.swap (a, b) = (b, a)
```

You can pass anything to these functions, and they'll always work, because their definitions make no assumption whatsoever on what can be done with those objects, as they just shuffle/ditch them.

---

Similarly,

```hs
i' :: a
i' = 1
```

cannot compile because it's not true that `1` can represent a value of any type `a`. It can't represent a `String`, for instance, whereas the signature `i' :: a` is expressing the idea that you can put `i'` in any place, e.g. where a `Int` is expected, as much as where a generic `Num` is expected, or where a `String` is expected, and so on.

In other words, the above signature says that you can use `i'` in both of these statements:

```hs
j = i' + 1
k = i' ++ "str"
```

So the question is: just like we found some functions that have signatures not constraining their arguments in any way, do we have a value that inhabits every single type you can think of?

Yes, there are some values like that, and here are two of them:

```hs
i' :: a
i' = error ""

j' :: a
j' = undefined
```

They're all "bottoms", or ⊥.

---

(¹) By "usable" I mean that when you write it in some place where the code compiles, the code keeps compiling.